# Function which takes a string as parameter

Tags: kdb

In kdb I would like to have a function which takes a string as a parameter.

```
myfunc: {[strParam]
    .... 
}
```

However when I tried to invoke the function.

```
q) myfunc["test"]
```

It complains of `length` error. It seems that function sees `"test"` as passing 4 char parameters. How can I make the function expect a string?

Comment: Error is not because of input its because how you are using it inside function.  KDB accepts string as parameter. Check your operations that you are performing on input.

Answer (score 3):

A string in kdb is defined as a list of characters and so functions using them have to be able to deal with this.

```
q)count "test"
4
```

You can also use a symbol instead casting from a string using `` `symbol$"test" ``. A symbol is atomic and fixed width so can be useful to use as keys to a dictionary or in a table. Some functions for strings will still work on symbols e.g

```
q)upper `test
`TEST
```

while list operation will not work and you will have to turn it back into a string using `` string `test `` before using those operations.

When a length error is thrown and you go into the debug mode as shown by the q prompt having two brackets `q))`, you can use the functions `.z.ex` to show the failed function and `.z.ey` to see the failed arguments to narrow down which part is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error can appear due to multiple reasons.

```
q)f:{[p] show p}  //it works fine with any number of elements 
q)f["abc"]
"abc"

f:{[p] enlist[`k]!p}   //needs a list of single element
f["abc"]
'length

f[enlist "abc"]      
(enlist `k)!enlist "abc"

q)f:{[p] 1 2 3 4!p}    //the length of values is different from the length of keys
q)f["abc"]
'length

q)f["abcd"]
(1j, 2j, 3j, 4j)!"abcd"
```